# Forcefully iterate for loop in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, coffeescript

In some complex situations, you want to manually force your for loop to go to a different position:

```
for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  var object = objects[i];
  if(object.type == typeThatShouldOnlyDisplayOnce) {
    displayObject();
    i += jumpToValidPosition;
  }
}
```

How can this be done in CoffeeScript? CoffeeScript's for loops are like

```
for i in [0...100]
  doSomething()
```

And looking at the compiled Javascript code, this seems to be coming out to something more like

```
for (n = i = ref = 0, ref1 = 100; ref <= ref1 ? i < ref1 : i > ref1; n = ref <= ref1 ? ++i : --i) {
```

Is there a CoffeeScript way of forcefully jumping to another loop position?

Comment: Have you tried re-assigning `i`?

Comment: Yep, still jumps to the next value, not the reassigned one. Seems to be related to the fact that the compiled code is using `ref` and not `i/n`

Comment: Sorry I can't answer this one, but sidenote, this sort of iterator mutation is very prone to error and should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops are just syntactic sugar for a `while` loop so you could rewrite it as such:

```
i = 0
while i < objects.length
  object = objects[i]
  if object.type == typeThatShouldOnlyDisplayOnce
    displayObject()
    i += jumpToValidPosition
  else
    i++
```